# Associate a file with a process manually

Tags: bash, shell, process, ps

I have a simple locking mechanism where a process will win a lock, if it is able to call mkdir on a certain path x.

Want I want to do is have other processes be able to search for which process owns the lock.

One way to do that, would be to use `ps` and find which processes have open files - so what I want to do is associate x with the process that created it. How can I do that?

*For example, can I read the file, and determine which process id was responsible for creating it?*

Answer (score 1):

`lsof /path/to/directory` can tell which process has the file currently locked. Checking the FD column in the output:

u - file is open for reading and writing

w - file is open for write

r - file is open for read.

But anyway it shows which process has currently locked the file at a specified time, but you can't tell which process did create the file/dir.
As a solution, you can name the directory with the "PID" extension, i.e.:

```
mkdir /path/to/somedir/yourdir$$
```

or

```
mkdir /path/to/somedir/yourdir & echo $! > /path/to/pidfile
```

For more detailed logs about file operations, `loggedfs` may help. It allows to logs every operation in a filesystem (I belive it logs the PID that created the file).

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and I don't think it's possible to read a file and determine what PID created it. So what I've done is do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

mkdir x
# we have succeeded acquiring the lock

mkdir "x/$$"
# just wrote the PID of this process to a directory name within x
```

so now we can read the PID that created x, by just doing:

```
ls x
```